# Convert class-redux component to functional hooks component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Could someone help me convert this class component to functional component using React-Hooks?

My code for class component is the following:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PanelHeader from "components/PanelHeader/PanelHeader.js";
import ProductList from "components/ProductList/ProductList.js";
import jeans1 from "../assets/img/jeans/jeans1.jpg";
import jeans from "variables/jeans";
import { addCart } from "../redux/actions";
import { removeCart} from "../redux/actions";



class Jeans extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cart: []
    }
}



render () {
    return (
      <>
        <PanelHeader size="sm" />
        <ProductList 
          addToCart = {this.props.addCart}
          removeFromCart = {this.props.removeCart}
          products={jeans}
          image={jeans1}
          header='Jeans For Men'
          description='Foundation Of Contemporary Wardrobes, 
          Whether Tailored Or Super Skinny, Straight or Slim, 
          Biker or Destroyed, Our Denim Collection Caters To 
          Every Style And Silhouette.'
        />
      </>
      );
    }
  }


const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
  return {
      cart: state.cart
       }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        addCart: (product) => {dispatch(addCart(product))},
        removeCart: (product) => {dispatch(removeCart(product))}
      }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Jeans);
```

I know that instead of `mapStateToProps` I have to implement `useSelector` and instead of `mapDispatchToProps` must use `useDispatch`, however, I struggle a bit!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't seem to be using `this.props.cart` ? Neither are you setting the state's `cart` to anything?

Comment: @Prajwal Kulkarni So, what you would suggest to do? I want to hook "addToCart" and " RemoveFromCart" and make the component working like working with redux! It is working fine with redux, however I am trying to simplify code using React-Hooks!

Comment: Yes, it's totally doable. It's a general intuition that redux state is used across multiple components, and I assumed that you'll be using in this component as well, however, it is not mandatory to do so. If you are not planning to use redux state, you can safely skip using the `useSelector` hook. I've posted the answer with details, kindly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `useDispatch` and `useSelector` to convert class-based redux component to functional-based redux component. Although I don't see where you are making use of the redux state. I have anyway included making use of the `useSelector` hook. If you're planning not to use redux state anywhere in this component, you can skip using the `useSelector` hook.

```
import React from "react";
import {useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import PanelHeader from "components/PanelHeader/PanelHeader.js";
import ProductList from "components/ProductList/ProductList.js";
import jeans1 from "../assets/img/jeans/jeans1.jpg";
import jeans from "variables/jeans";
import { addCart } from "../redux/actions";
import { removeCart} from "../redux/actions";



export default function Jeans(){
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const cart = useSelector(state=>state.cart) //Cart values can be accessed using the cart constant.
  
  
  const addToCartHandler = (product) =>{
     dispatch(addCart(product))
  }
  const removeFromCartHandler = (product) =>{
     dispatch(removeCart(product))
  }


    return (
      <>
        <PanelHeader size="sm" />
        <ProductList 
          addToCart = {addToCartHandler}
          removeFromCart = {removeFromCartHandler}
          products={jeans}
          image={jeans1}
          header='Jeans For Men'
          description='Foundation Of Contemporary Wardrobes, 
          Whether Tailored Or Super Skinny, Straight or Slim, 
          Biker or Destroyed, Our Denim Collection Caters To 
          Every Style And Silhouette.'
        />
      </>
      );
  }
```

Comment: @ Prajwal Kulkarni Thank you. It worked! I did not thing creating the "addToCartHandler" and "removeFromCartHandler" functions, too!

Comment: You can alternatively also use shorthand notation by using the arrow function within the JSX, like `<ProductList addToCart={(product)=>addCart(product)} ...`, but it'd make code readability harder and also the code on the whole, less modular. But, you as a developer, have the choice to choose the one, which fits you best.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code,
I have added `useCallback` for batter performance. And `cart` which are not used in your code but you can use `cart` on component

```js
import React, {Component, useCallback} from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import PanelHeader from "components/PanelHeader/PanelHeader.js";
import ProductList from "components/ProductList/ProductList.js";
import jeans1 from "../assets/img/jeans/jeans1.jpg";
import jeans from "variables/jeans";
import { addCart } from "../redux/actions";
import { removeCart} from "../redux/actions";

const Jeans = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);

  const addToCart = useCallback(product => dispatch(addCart(product)), [dispatch]);

  const removeFromCart = useCallback(product => dispatch(removeCart(product)), [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <PanelHeader size="sm" />
      <ProductList 
        addToCart = {addToCart}
        removeFromCart = {removeFromCart}
        products={jeans}
        image={jeans1}
        header='Jeans For Men'
        description='Foundation Of Contemporary Wardrobes, 
        Whether Tailored Or Super Skinny, Straight or Slim, 
        Biker or Destroyed, Our Denim Collection Caters To 
        Every Style And Silhouette.'
      />
    </>
    );
};


export default Jeans;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is to make sure this component is wrapped inside a `Provider`, which you should have already done.

```
// This is where you stored your redux actions, may be different in your case
import { addCart, removeCart } from "actions";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import jeans1 from "../assets/img/jeans/jeans1.jpg";
import jeans from "variables/jeans";
import PanelHeader from "components/PanelHeader/PanelHeader.js";
import ProductList from "components/ProductList/ProductList.js";

const Jeans = () => {
  // state unused for some reasons
  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleAddToCart = product => dispatch(addCart(product));
  const handleRemoveFromCart = product => dispatch(removeCart(product));

  return (
    <>
      <PanelHeader size="sm" />
      <ProductList
        addToCart={handleAddToCart}
        removeFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart}
        products={jeans}
        image={jeans1}
        header='Jeans For Men'
        description='Foundation Of Contemporary Wardrobes, 
          Whether Tailored Or Super Skinny, Straight or Slim, 
          Biker or Destroyed, Our Denim Collection Caters To 
          Every Style And Silhouette.'
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Jeans;
```

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer. Adding the export statement as well.

Comment: @ Matthew Kwong Thank you so much! It works fine. I could not think that I had to create: "handleAddToCart" and "handleRemoveFromCart" functions, too!